# Writing a cookie inside WKUIWebView visible from Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview, mobile-safari, wkwebview

I'm trying to load a web Url from inside my app and I need to set a cookie. At the moment I'm using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_myURL]];
```

but this approach results in my app switching to Mobile Safari which is quite ugly as the user loses the focus on my app. Loading the web page inside the new *WKUIWebView* (and using *NSHttpCookieStorage*) is not an option as apparently those cookie would be sandboxed. Is there any other way I can create a cookie which is visible from Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS9 you can use the [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/) which does share cookies with Safari mobile. You can use this in conjunction with custom URL schemes or universal links to ["communicate" between them](https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f#).

Comment: I need to read cookies from Safari app to inside my app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Applications having access to Safari's cookies would be a security concern.

If you have control over the site that you are opening then you could do something with a one-time login code in the url as a request parameter.